# converting varchar to Int SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I needed help with something I am not entirely sure how to resolve.

This is my code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT

Nr_of_Times_Cust_No_Appears=CASE WHEN CAST(a.TV_Code AS Int)-CAST(BB_Code AS Int)=0 THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY BB_Code) ELSE 'Not same' END
FROM table
```

Basically, the above code is meant to make sure that the substraction of TV Code and BB Code is Zero(0) if not then 'Not Same'. TV Code and BB Code are both varchar that are CAST to Int. The problem lies in the ELSE ' NOT SAME'.

This is the output I get from SQL SERVER Management Studio:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Not same' to data type int.
```

What should I do to make it work?

UPDATE: I finally found the workaround.

`CAST(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY XX) AS Varchar).....` It worked!!!!

Comment: But why do you store int values as char (or what data type it is)? Integer values are supposed to be stored in integer columns.

Comment: Answer is in the error. You cant convert 'Not same' to an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is simply occurring as your destination column can only have one data type.

The first part of your `CASE` statement is effictively setting the column type to expect an integer, so when you hit the `ELSE` section and try to insert `Not Same`, you're getting the error.

Sample:

```
SELECT  Num
INTO    #T
FROM    ( SELECT    '1' AS Num
          UNION
          SELECT    '2'
        ) AS val

SELECT  CASE WHEN Num = '1' THEN CAST(Num AS INT)
             ELSE 'Not 1'
        END AS OutputVal
FROM    #T 

DROP TABLE #T
```

Gives you:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Not 1' to data type int.

So you need to insert an acceptable value, which could be `NULL`:

Sample:

```
SELECT  Num
INTO    #T
FROM    ( SELECT    '1' AS Num
          UNION
          SELECT    '2'
        ) AS val

SELECT  CASE WHEN Num = '1' THEN CAST(Num AS INT)
             ELSE NULL
        END AS OutputVal
FROM    #T 

DROP TABLE #T
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the output of your CASE statement is returning count(*) (an integer) from THEN 'Not same' (a string) from the ELSE. They need to be the same types. If you cast your count(*) to a string you will be fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Nr_of_Times_Cust_No_Appears=
      CASE WHEN CAST(a.TV_Code AS Int)-CAST(BB_Code AS Int)=0 
           THEN CAST(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY BB_Code) AS VARCHAR)  
           ELSE 'Not same' 
           END
FROM table
```

**Alternative:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Nr_of_Times_Cust_No_Appears=
      CASE WHEN CAST(a.TV_Code AS Int)-CAST(BB_Code AS Int)=0 
           THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY BB_Code) 
           ELSE -1 
           END
FROM table
```

In the consuming code i.e. User Interface, if Nr_of_Times_Cust_No_Appears < 0 then show 'Not same'!

Comment: Thanks for  the example.  It prompts an error OVER message.

Comment: @user3197575 See amended example or alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Check variable Nr_of_Times_Cust_No_Appears. It seems to be int, but you try to set it 'Not same'.

Comment: I think since I am doing substraction after CASTING varchar TV&BB Codes, the ELSE message should be in "int" as well. I tried doing this and it works. I thought having 'Not Same' would be a better error message than Devil's number,6666666666666666666666. Haha

Comment: The 'correct' way to do this would be to use a number which `count(*)` can't return. Since you must be getting at least one row to do the comparison, the `count(*)` won't be returning `null`, so why not use that? Then you can easily check to see if your column `Nr_of_Times_Cust_No_Appears` is `null` when you are using the results elsewhere, and display your error message as appropriate.  That, or cast your `count` to a `varchar`...